# How to manage exception from command in reactive programming?

Tags: exception, rxjs

According to Uncle Bob in his Clean Code book: Functions should either do something or answer something.

So commands (do something) must not to return some information. But, it's useful to know if the command was executed without error.

For that, we can throw an exception that we catch in try/catch.

But, the reactive way (rxjs) seems to be little bit different.

If we take this code sample:

```
function test(var: number): Observable<void> {
  if(var == 2)
    return Rx.Observable.throw("error")

  return Rx.Observable.of(var)
}

let foo = test(1).catch(err => Rx.Observable.of(err))
foo.subscribe(val => console.log(val))

let foo2 = test(2).catch(err => Rx.Observable.of(err))
foo2.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

Console log of foo displays 1 and it's quite logic. Console log of foo2 displays "error" and it's logic too.

Maybe, I don't use correctly throw and .catch?

To use the catch operator, I have to return an Observable otherwise I have a javascript error (Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined).

That's mean we always must to return something?

Comment: Not really clear on what you are trying to accomplish. The second argument for the `subscribe` operator is the `onError` callback. You could "catch" your exception there.

Comment: I want to know what's the best way in rxjs to manage exception

Comment: I guess it depends on how you want to "manage" the exception. If you want it to end the stream then don't use the `catch` operator. If you want to know when the error occurs then use the `onError` callback on the `subscribe`. If you want to handle the exception and not end the stream then use the `catch` operator and return something that is not exceptional. If you want to suppress the output of the catch because it is useless to the rest of your stream then use the `filter` operator to remove it. If you want to retry on error then use the `retry` operator or one of its variants.